# Регулярные выражения. .+ vs .*

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Объясните пожалуйста разницу между `.+` и `.*`. По моему они оба должны "вывести, найти или подчеркнуть" весь текст данный в файле. Когда я в `regexr.com` пишу `.+` он находит весь текст  но когда я пишу выражение  `.*` то выводится ошибка `infinite`.

P.S. Флаг global активирован

Comment: Запрос в студию! .+ это хотя бы один, .* - в т.ч. ничего. Иногда бывает рекурсия, если есть вложения паттернов...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.+` - любой(ые) символ(ы) в количестве 1 или более. `.*` - любой(ые) символ(ы) в количестве 0 или более. Второе выражение соответствует абсолютно любому тексту, включая пустую строку, 1 - любой строке, кроме пустой.

В python выражение `.*` нормально компилируется, и действительно соответствует любой строке.

Comment: Да и на Apache `.*` не вызывает проблем